# Mysql query for insert if JSON fields are not fixed

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-2.7

I have a JSON data that is inconsistent with fields.

```
{
  "Firsthouse": {
  "Doors": "10",
  "windows": "9"
   },     

  "Secondhouse": {
  "doors": "1",
  "windows": "10",
  "pools": "2"
   } 
}
```

In "Secondhouse" field "pools" is present while it is absent in "Firsthouse".
If I want to write an insert query, do I need to have 6 different queries for presence/absence of such fields, like below:

```
#This is a query when 3 fields are present
 query = "insert into table (doors,windows,pools) values (%s,%s,%s)"
 q_tup = data_list_3Fields
 cursor.executemany(query, q_tup)  

#This is a query when 4 fields are present
 query = "insert into table (doors,windows,pools,floors) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
 q_tup = data_list_4Fields
 cursor.executemany(query, q_tup)
```

Is there a proper approach to do this?

Comment: how did you define **6** queries?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks for replying. I am thinking to put them under if-else statement, checking for the fields that are present and framing the query accordingly. But, that would need 6 combinations, I guess I am thinking in a wrong way. Hoping for a nicer idea.

Comment: post/describe those "6 combinations" to clarify your conditions

Comment: Are you using a version of MySQL that has the JSON Data type?  5.7 or 8.0?  If yes then you are able to write the JSON object/array with one statement.    If you are not using the JSON data type, then you are mostly likely writing out a string and that can be done once also.  Either case there is no need for multiple input statetments.